# Monitor hosting environment for spam keywords

Tags: spam-prevention, nagios

What environment-independent tools are available to detect new spam blogs or comments appearing on a hosting infrastructure?

As an occasional hosting provider, we want to watch for new blogs or comments which appear spammy, but avoid relying on plugins or modules in the CMS environment (because these are easy to circumvent, or expose only to Google).

A (pseudo) example would be to set up Google Alert for "viagra ip:10.0.0.1", where 10.0.0.1 is the front-facing IP of the servers. (Google doesn't offer such an advanced operator term though ...)

Seems I'm looking for a combination of Nagios + Google Alerts + ( ??? ) ... what does fill this space?

Answer (score 0):

I would setup an hourly cronjob that wgets the entire website then greps the resulting files for whatever spam strings you're looking for an alerts on a hit. Let me know if you'd like me to hack up a quick example, or if thats not the direction you were thinking.

Comment: Thanks - it's an approach, but I guess I hoped to leverage other people already in the act of "downloading the internet" rather than having to do it myself. wgeting some of the sites we host would take "considerable" resources ;)

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to get wget to do exactly what you want. Something like:
`wget -r -e robots=off -U Firefox -A .html <ip>`

I mean, one way or another you have to fully crawl each site, correct? I can't imagine the HTML would end up being that large. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Based on your Twitter profile, I suspect you may just want to sell me your services restarting Apache hourly ;) ... You are right that wget could do this, and that we prob shouldn't trust Google to do it for us, but downloading all sites hourly in order to pipe them to grep is just too intensive an approach.

Comment: Hey, apache ain't gunna restart itself ;-) I still think you should give it a go, could have it sleep a second between fetching each page. Unless you're hosting the library of congress I think this should be doable, nightly at least. There might be some smarter way to just pipe everything to stdout and grep the stream that way so you avoid creating all the files, but not sure the cleaneast way to handle that logic.